# Vuex map functions with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, typescript4.0

I have an interface for my state (game namespace) that looks like the following:

```
interface GameState {
  selectedTab: number;
  timeout: number;
  snackbar: boolean;
  text: string;
  doneTasks: number;
  taskTypes: TaskType[];
  stages: Stage[];
}
```

i'm trying to map 'taskTypes' inside a component using mapState like this:

```
...mapState('game', {
  taskTypes: (state: GameState): TaskType[] => state.taskTypes,
}),
```

i get the following error "Argument of type '{ taskTypes: (state: GameState) => TaskType[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'."

when defining the "state" parameter type of the function as 'any' it compiles and works, so i tried to "debug" that function in devtools and see what the "state" param holds, and it holds my game state, which has the exact props that are defined in the GameState interface.

does anyone know why ts won't let me define the "state" param with it's correct type (that is the whole purpose of defining interfaces in the first place and avoiding 'any')

this also doesn't work:

```
...mapState({
  taskTypes: ({ state }: Store<GameState>): TaskType[] => state.taskTypes,
}),
```

has anyone ever came across such problem? any ideas how of the best practice way to deal with it?

goes same for mapActions etc...

**UPDATE**
i try to give better typings to my store and modules. right now they are the following:
main store:

```
export default new Store<RootState>({
  modules: {
    users,
    game,
  },
});
```

with RootState being:

```
export interface RootState {
  game: GameState;
  users: UserState;
}
```

game module:

```
type GameActionContext = ActionContext<GameState, RootState>;

const gameModule: Module<GameState, RootState> = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    selectedTab: 0,
    timeout: 5000,
    snackbar: false,
    text: '',
    doneTasks: 0,
    taskTypes: [...],
    stages: [...],
  } as GameState,
  mutations: {/*Mutations*/} as MutationTree<GameState>,
  actions: {/*Actions*/} as ActionTree<GameState, RootState>,
};

export default gameModule;
```

I'm trying to map a state obejct the following way:

```
...mapState({
      taskTypes: (state): TaskType[] => state.GameState.taskTypes
})
```

but i'm receiving the error:

> (parameter) state: unknown - Object is of type 'unknown'

Comment: It should work.  Maybe you should show the whole component and possibly the root store

Comment: Does it work with Typescript v3.9.7?

Comment: no, using typescipt 4.0.3. the component basically has nothing right now, only this computed mapState function. the store basically has a modules object that contains two namespaced states

Comment: The point of showing the code is maybe you did something else wrong that you don't realize.  For example "namespaced states" doesn't sound right, it would be "namespaced modules".  But there could be a structural mistake or typo anywhere

Comment: yeah they are namespaced modules. i updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting the best solution i came up with so far (as far for least code and typed code):

```
...mapState({
  taskTypes: (state): TaskType[] => (state as RootState).game.taskTypes,
}),
```

because state will always be equal to RootState that casting will always stay the same for every mapState. can't say im completely happy with this solution but for now it seems to be the best one (doesn't require any extra interfaces / long lines of casting types)

Answer (score 1):

I've generally had to cast the objects as unknown and then to the actual type.

You can try this approach, created a generic type like this that basically will make the values available as functions:

```
export type Computed<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: () => T[K];
};
```

Now you can use this in a component like this:

```
...((mapState('auth', ['taskTypes']) as unknown) as Pick<Computed<GameState>, 'taskTypes'>)
```

Now `this.taskTypes` should be be typed.

Comment: thanks, i came up with something similar but it seems to me like a hassle to cast mapstate like that for each prop im mapping from the state, it seems like making the code look more complicated and less readable. though right now this seems like the only solution that works

Comment: Yes, that's true. Now that I think of it, you can try creating your own typed `mapXX` functions. Would make them a lot easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a generic type to `mapState`.

```
...mapState<GameState>('game', {
  taskTypes: (state: GameState): TaskType[] => state.taskTypes,
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message on mapGetters the way I have managed to type it inside a Vue2 component correctly is like this:

```
...(mapGetters("module", ['someGetter']) as {someGetter: () => boolean}),
...(mapState("appModule", ["appIsLoading"]) as {appIsLoading: () => boolean;}),
...(mapMutations("appModule", ["SET_APP_IS_LOADING"]) as {SET_APP_IS_LOADING: (payload: boolean) => void;}),
...(mapActions("appModule", ["extendLockTime"]) as {extendLockTime: () => void;}),
```

With this type hinting and type checking is correct inside the component.