# Vue with typescript Object is of type "unknown"

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

When i'm complining my vue code i get error:

`[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/resources/js/Components/Language/LanguagePicker.vue.ts(13,41)`

`TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.`

On this line i have mapState function from vuex:

```
computed: {
        ...mapState<State, any>({
            currentLanguage: (state: State): Language | null => state.currentLanguage
        })
    },
```

How can i fix that?

Comment: Is the `Language` type imported correctly?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, i have this error in every file with mapState

Comment: Vuex helpers like mapState have innate typing problems . It's preferable to not use them with TS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66189921/vuex-map-functions-with-typescript